# How to phrase a requirement where two of four explicitly listed things are needed

Tags: sentence-request

Let’s say there are four things hat might satisfy your desires: apples, oranges, mangos, and kiwis.

If you’re content with having just one of the fruits above, you might, in a sentence, tell someone, “If you have apples, oranges, mangos, *or* kiwis, I’ll be happy.”

If you won’t be satisfied until you have all four, in a sentence you might phrase that as “If you have apples, oranges, mangos, *and* kiwis, I’ll be happy.”

But what if you want only two of the four fruits? (Or three?) How would one naturally convey that in a single sentence? Someone said to me, “If you have two of apples, oranges, mangos, and kiwis...”, but while that sounds wrong to me, I’m not sure how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I'd be happy **with any two of them**.

That might not be quite precise enough to indicate that you want two different kinds, as opposed to two apples or whatever, so I guess you could be more precise with

> I'd be happy **with any two of different kinds**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't there is an easy "natural" way. When you say "requirement" I think of engineering where being explicit is more important than sounding natural.

> I need my selection of fruits to be taken from exactly two of the following four categories: apples, oranges, mangos, and kiwis.

or

> I two fruits, each from a different catagory, and each coming from the following categories: apples, oranges, mangos, and kiwis.

Answer (score 0):

> Choosing from apples, oranges, mangoes, and kiwis, I would be happy to have exactly two types of fruit.

Note that this does not preclude having two apples and three mangoes (for instance). If you want exactly one fruit from two of the types:

> Choosing from apples, oranges, mangoes, and kiwis, I would be happy to have one from each of two types of fruit.